# Name of a roleplaying supplement, 80s, D20 system, heavy on Alchemy?

Tags: product-identification, fantasy, d20-system

I once had a roleplaying "supplement" - that was the title, it was actually an almost complete rpg - like this:

- the (scarcely described) setting was supposed to be Atlantis
- level and class system
- I believe first published in the 80s, in the US
- Huge alchemy system with tons of recipes
- maybe half a dozen magic classes with own spell list
- classes and skills to play classical medieval fantasy and also eastern/wuxia/Jidei Geki heroes (martial artists, monks, ninja)
- Combat mechanic revolved around a d20, skill checks around a d100, attributes where mostly <20 and played little direct role (A bit similar to Rifts)
- The German title was "Arkanum", however that's used so often and is not protected that it's useless as a search term (or my google fu is horrible).

I'd like to know what it was called and the usual publishing information (authors etc.).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this the game you are looking for?:  [*The Arcanum* or *Atlantis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantis_(role-playing_game))

Comment: yes! That's the one.